# SOLR behaves differently on XML and JSON output

Tags: solr, lucene

I try those to requests:

`http://localhost:8080/solr/core/select/?q=title:mario&start=0&rows=10&wt=xml` works fine

`http://localhost:8080/solr/core/select/?q=title:mario&start=0&rows=10&wt=json` doesn't work!
returns

HTTP Status 400 - undefined field tags

type Status report

message undefined field tags

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (undefined field tags).

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: mmm, that's weird. Are you setting any default value for your standard request handler in your solrconfig.xml? Solr is looking for a tags field which is not in your schema I guess, but you're not mentioning it in your query. Also, doesn't make sense that it has a different behaviour based on the wt parameter, I would check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
For people who may encounter the same weird behaviour, how I got there:

I changed the **data-dir** property to another directory (a data-dir of another SOLR core, with different database, fields..)

Just re-indexing the index solved the issue.